# How to find all substrings between two delimiters in php?

Tags: php, string, parsing

For example, assume there is a string

```
"var name=cat; *bunch of random strings* var name=dog; *bunch of random strings* var name=cow; *bunch of random strings*"
```

I want to parse this string and find all the strings between the two delimiters, "name=" and ";". So, I want to extract the words cat, dog, and cow and put them in an array. Any idea how I should do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know that explode does the trick, but this seems to:

```
$string = "var name=cat; *bunch of random strings* var name=dog;*bunch of random strings*var name=cow;*bunch of random strings*";
preg_match_all('/name=([^;]+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

or, as a function :

```
function wizbangStringParser ($string) {
    preg_match_all('/name=([^;]+)/', $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```